# Django-Streamlit integration

Tags: django, render, streamlit

Can I integrate Streamlit with Django ?
I tried but didn't know what to render ?

I used the [this code](https://github.com/Sven-Bo/excel-webapp-streamlit) inside the django app

Comment: For the most part, anything can be integrated with anything. The better question is what are you trying to accomplish? Streamlit and Django are both web frameworks, so unless you are really doing something complex, you probably need one or the other.

Answer (score 1):

A simple idea is to run the Streamlit separatly and integrate into your App by IFrame. For example if you run streamlit on `http://localhost:8501/` you can include that in your HTML:

```
<iframe src="http://localhost:8501/" name="iframe_a" height="400px" width="100%" title="Iframe Example"></iframe>
```